# Set a pointer to the nth address of char array

Tags: c, pointers

Hi I'm trying to set a pointer to the nth char of an array:

```
// create pointer 
char *originalPointer;

// malloc an arrary of 10 chars
originalPointer = (char *) malloc(10);

// create new pointer
char* setPtrAsNthCharOforiginalPointer;

// **** how to set it to the nth spot of ****
setPtrAsNthCharOfOriginalPointer = &originalPointer + 4;
```

Comment: `originalPointer` is already an address so no need to use `&`

Comment: the result is the 5th character in the array (starts at 0 offset) to get a pointer to the 5th char use: &(originalPointer[4])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the address operator

```
too_long_name = originalPointer + 4 ;
```

Answer (score 2):

As the array name `originalPointer` itself holds the base address of the `array`, you dont need the `&` operator

```
too_long_name = originalPointer + 4;
```

And dont type cast the return of `malloc`

```
originalPointer = malloc(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand how to do this consider a simple example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char s[] = "Hello Paul Hawk";
    size_t i;

    for ( i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++ )
    {
        char *p = s + i;
        printf( "%c", *p );
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The output will be

```
Hello Paul Hawk
```